# Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, table

Добрый вечер уважаемые знатоки.
Подскажите где закралась ошибка. Язык изучаю совсем недавно. Поэтому если есть возможность объяснить поподробнее, буду благодарен вдвойне.

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: [Пишут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16565213/5045688), что ноду нужно клонировать.

Comment: Это я видел : ) Только не пойму что надо клонировать.